# Suppress all output from a Powershell script called from another Powershell Script

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script (`a.ps1`) which calls another PowerShell script (`b.ps1`). I want to suppress all non-error output from `b.ps1`. If it matters, `b.ps1` has to take in an argument.

I have tried the following contents of `a.ps1`

`b.ps1 -arg1 "arg1" | Out-Null`

`b.ps1 -arg1 "arg1" *>&1`

`b.ps1 -arg1 "arg1" *>&1 | Out-Null`

`Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { b.ps1 -arg1 "arg1" } | Out-Null`

All of these still result in the prints from `b.ps1` being printed to the console that called `a.ps1`.

I do not own the content of `b.ps1` and cannot change the file at all.

Contents of `b.ps1` in this example:

```
param(
  [string]$arg1
)

Write-Host $arg1
```

Comment: under normal circumstances, the output of `Write-Host` **_cannot be suppressed or redirected_**. i recommend you switch to one of the `Write-*` cmdlets that CAN be suppressed or redirected.

Comment: `*>&1 | Out-Null` should work actually but it will redirect any useful object output as well.  `6>null` will redirect the information stream only (which is what Write-Host uses) to null which is probably better IMO  [Redirectable output streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.1#redirectable-output-streams)

Comment: I should mention that these should work if you are using PowerShell version 5.0+ -- "Starting in Windows PowerShell 5.0, Write-Host is a wrapper for Write-Information This allows you to use Write-Host to emit output to the information stream. This enables the capture or suppression of data written using Write-Host while preserving backwards compatibility." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-7.1#description